# MySql Multiple Averages

Tags: mysql

I have a table, in which i have some prices stated for different types of hotel rooms.
I want to query so that i get the average price of every single room, however mySQL does only give me 1 avg, instead of 2 which i need. My code is as follows:

```
SELECT AVG(Price) From `Room` WHERE (Type='Double') OR (Type='single');
```

I guess its my OR statement that seems to bug me..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks any sort of effort

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT AVG(Price), `Type`
FROM `Room`
GROUP BY `Type`
```

Comment: If i want to exclude or write the code for each type individually, what should i then do?

Comment: You can add your WHERE (Type='Double') OR (Type='single') after the FROM statement

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT AVG(case when Type='Double' then Price else 0 end) as avg_double_price,
       AVG(case when Type='Single' then Price else 0 end) as avg_single_price,
       sum(Type='Double') as double_count,
       sum(Type='Single') as single_count
From `Room`
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer :)

however i think i didnt explain myself good enough! 

I have prices stated for double rooms, and prices stated for single rooms.
I want sql to count respectively an average price for single rooms and double rooms.

Comment: I updated the answer. If you add example data and expected output your question will be much clearer.